# Inequalities between Gauss and Lebesgue measures

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $[0,1]$ and let $\mu$ be the lebesgue measure and $\lambda$ be Gauss's measure:

$\lambda(B)=\int_B \frac{1}{1+x}dx$

I want to show that there exists positive constants $a$ and $A$ such that

$$a \mu(B) \leq \lambda(B) \leq A \mu(B)$$

for all Lebesgue measurable sets $B$.

Now, the right hand side inequality is easy after noting that $\frac{1}{1+x} \leq 1 $ for all $x \in [0,1]$, we get $A=1$. But what about the left hand side inequality? I thought about proving it for intervals and then using that every Lebesgue measurable set can be approximated by a union of intervals. Does this make sense?

However, if this method of proof was ok and I considered the interval $[a,b]$, I would still need to prove that

$$f(a,b) = \frac{\ln(\frac{1+b}{1+a})}{b-a}$$

is bounded below by something strictly greater than $0$ in the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (0,1)$ and $(1,1)$.

Welcome any thoughts, comments, ideas, etc. Thanks as usual!

Comment: btw, I use to think that Gauss measure refers to the normal distribution, so your notation is a bit confusing.

Comment: this is called gauss's measure, although i forgot to divide by $\log 2$...

Comment: apparently it is used in number theory. It is related to continued fractions and the so called Gauss map. It turns out that the Gauss measure is ergodic wrt to the Gauss map.

Comment: interesting, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have $\frac{1}{1+x}\geq \frac12$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and thus
$$
  \lambda (B) = \int_{[0,1]}1_B(x)\frac{1}{1+x}\mu(\mathrm dx) \geq \frac 12 \mu(B).
$$
In general, let us consider some measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$ and let $\mathrm d\lambda = f \mathrm d\mu$ where $\mu$ and $f$ are arbitrary. Suppose that for some $a$ it holds that $a\mu(B)\leq \lambda(B), \;\forall B\in \Sigma$. Then
$$
  \int_B(f - a)\mathrm d\mu\geq 0\quad \forall B\in \Sigma
$$
and as a result $a\in \{a'\in \Bbb R: \mu\{f< a'\} = 0\}.$ [The supremum of this set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum) is
$$
  \operatorname{ess\;inf} f := \sup\{a':\mu(f<a') = 0\}.
$$
Thus, in general you can say that
$$
  \operatorname{ess\;inf} f\cdot \mu(B)\leq \lambda(B) \leq \operatorname{ess\;sup} f\cdot \mu(B),\quad \forall B\in \Sigma
$$
and these bounds are the optimal ones.

Comment: hahaha! of course...as simple as that. :)

Comment: @chango: I updated my answer a bit

Comment: I guess this implies that then the set of $L_1$ functions is the same in both cases, right? Proving this would probably make use of the definition of the integral as the supremum of the integrals of simple functions less than $f$.

Comment: Its easier yet for this last bit to note that the above inequality implies that $\mu << \lambda$ and $\lambda << \mu$. Thus one can use Radon-Nikodym